# Problems with Structs (C++)

Tags: c++, struct, compiler-errors

I want to use a Struct but dont't know where to define it. That's my code at the moment:

> Header file (Datos.h)

```
#ifndef DATOS_H
#define DATOS_H

using namespace std;

class Datos {
public:
    Datos();
    void rellenarDatos();

    struct KeyData;
    struct BBDD;

};
```

> Implementation File (Datos.cpp)

```
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include "Datos.h"

using namespace std;

Datos::Datos() {  
};

struct KeyData {
        int Key;
        string data;
};

struct BBDD {
    KeyData DNI[N];
    KeyData Nombre[N];
    KeyData Apellido[N];
    KeyData Direccion[N];
};

void Datos::rellenarDatos() {
    BBDD.DNI[i].Key = 100;
    BBDD.Nombre[i].Key = 100;
    BBDD.Apellido[i].Key = 100; 
    BBDD.Direccion[i].Key = 100;

    BBDD.DNI[i].data = "hello";
    BBDD.Nombre[i].data = "hello";
    BBDD.Apellido[i].data = "hello";
    BBDD.Direccion[i].data = "hello";   
};
```

The compiler drops error like this:

```
Datos.cpp:25:7: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
   BBDD.DNI[i].Key = 100;
```

Where is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Put `KeyData` and `BBDD` declarations in the header.

Comment: think you need to instantiate the struct

Comment: If I put KeyData and BBDD in the header it throws the same error. So, Where can I instantiate the struct? on every methods where I use the struct?

Comment: You need to instantiate the struct this way: `struct BBDD foo` and inside the BBDD you need to do the same for `KeyData` doing something like this: `struct KeyData bar`.

Comment: @WoozyCoder In C++ you don't need to add `struct` before struct-name, like you do in C.

Comment: so I need to put struct KeyData DNI[N]; in place of KeyData DNI[N];?

Comment: @MarioNavarroClaras No, you don't.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just messed it up... I don't know what I was thinking of... Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems.

First of all, `BBDD` is a type, not an object.
This is the immediate cause of the error message.

Second, in your class definition, you have forward-declared two structs in the scope of the class `Datos`.

The full names of these are `Datos::KeyData` and `Datos::BBDD`, so to define them you could write

```
struct Datos::KeyData {
        int Key;
        string data;
};

struct Datos::BBDD {
    Datos::KeyData DNI[N];
    Datos::KeyData Nombre[N];
    Datos::KeyData Apellido[N];
    Datos::KeyData Direccion[N];
};
```

On the other hand, it looks like you want to have a member of the type `BBDD`.
In that case, put the definitions inside the class definition:

```
class Datos {
public:
    Datos();
    void rellenarDatos();

    struct KeyData {
        int Key;
        string data;
    };

    struct BBDD {
        KeyData DNI[N];
        KeyData Nombre[N];
        KeyData Apellido[N];
        KeyData Direccion[N];
    };

    BBDD bbdd;
};

// ...

void Datos::rellenarDatos() {
    // ...
    bbdd.DNI[i].Key = 100;
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Structs are data structures like classes. What you did now is define a data structure of type BBDD. To access members of this structure you need to define an instance of this struct. You can do this either as a class member in your class or as a global variable. Just don't forget that with structs you need to append the keyword struct to your definition.

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is in your Header file, when you declare the struct members of your class:

```
struct KeyData;
struct BBDD;
```

When you define a struct, it becomes a type. If you want to use it, you have to *create an instance* of it, not declare another struct. Say I want a struct called Classroom that holds the room number and the subject taught there. I would define it like your structs in your .cpp file:

```
struct Classroom {
     int roomNumber;
     string subject;
}
```

Now when I want to use it, I use *Classroom*, not struct:

```
Classroom myClassroom;
myClassroom.roomnumber = 25;
myClassroom.subject = "Computer Science";
```

so in your case, rather than writing

```
struct KeyData;
struct BBDD;
```

you should write:

```
KeyData KeyData;
BBDD BBDD;
```

...although I would recommend changing either the struct name or the instance name so that they aren't identical to avoid confusion and potentially compiler errors!

EDIT: Note that this won't solve all the errors with your code - you have some other issues within that snippet of undeclared variables (which may not be an issue for you if "N" and "i" in your .cpp are defined elsewhere) which you will have to declare or pass as arguments as required, but the above will fix the errors with your struct declaration.